# Why is my port forwarding not working?

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I port forwarded `45555` and tested the port locally using [PortQryV2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148), with the command `PortQry -n <my local ip> -e 45555` and the verdict was `LISTENING` but when I tried to listen from the public IP address, `PortQry -n <my public ip> -e 45555`, the verdict was `FILTERED`. I assumed it had something to do with my firewall, or maybe the router firewall, so I disabled each then tried again, still no success. I even tried adding port rules in the firewall to allow inbound and outbound connections for this port. Could you kindly guide me on how to fix this? Please try to use layman terms where possible, I am not very able on these matters.

I am using a PPPoE connection. My router is TP-Link Wireless N Router WR840N. The port is a `TCP/UDP` port. I got the public IP from Google by searching [my ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip).

[image: Here is my WAN setup]
this is my WAN setup. My WAN IP is very different from the IP from google. But the DNS server match up except for last 3 digits.

Comment: Note that with most routers, you cannot test the public IP for a port forward from the inside. A feature called Hairpin NAT is required, but it is only usually available with enterprise grade routers.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I also tried [YouGetSignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and it also said my port was closed

Comment: can you verify that the public IP you see in your google search is assigned to the WAN side of your router? if the public IP is originating from a system upstream, then the traffic won't get to your port-forward rule. can you verify the wan IP from your router console?

Comment: The IP address under WAN is completely different from the IP on google. The DNS server matches, except for the last 3 digits.

Comment: By DNS server IP i mean, there is another ip before 8.8.8.8, that IP matched, except the last 3 digits. I inserted a picture for clarification.

Comment: If the WAN address your router says is different from the address that Google shows, your ISP may be using carrier-grade NAT, which will make it impossible for you to do conventional port forwarding. One way to tell for sure is if your router shows your WAN IP as starting with 100, 192, 172.16-32, or 10.